# Call custom javascript before loading any SPFX webparts

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepoint-framework

I have a requirement, where i want to fetch certain properties from user profile.For this i have created a file which fetches data from user profile and store in global variable.
I was able to add script to modern page and classic page ( Add-PnPJavaScriptLink )

Based on these user profile properties each of my webpart are getting loaded on modern page.

i dont want to call the userprofile js each time for each webpart.

I just want to call it once.Once present in global variable i should be able to access it for all other webparts

But the problem is the custom javascript is getting called after webpart is rendered

any suggestions ?

Comment: Did you tried the following? It describes exactly your problem ;-) https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/share-data-between-web-parts

Comment: Did you find any solution? Am facing same kind of issue :(

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint does have a function in the `onclick` event that looks for any `PreSaveItem` events.  You can create a function called `PreSaveAction();` within you client code to have you custom actions run before SharePoint does it's thing after the Save button is clicked.  Look at a Save button in a form in Developer Tools, and you will see what I am saying.  There is a check at the beginning that says:

```
onclick="(!PreSaveItem()) return false; blah blah blah"
```

Try running this function:

```
PreSaveAction() {
    //do my stuff here
}
```

Make sure this function is place above any `$(document).ready(function() {});`, `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("myCustom");`, or any other page ready type event for it to fire.  This should work for you.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a global function which would return a promise and also cache the data? Only first call to the function would cause loading the data for the user profile. Subsequent calls would be handled from cache. 
Using promises would also solve your problem with async calls.

More about promises: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises

Example:

```
function getDataGlobal(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Your api call here
    if (/* everything turned out fine */) {
        resolve(yourApiData);
    }
    else {
        reject(Error("It broke"));
    }
    });
 }
//In webpart
 getDataGlobal().then(function(result) {
    console.log(result); /* result is the "yourApiData" from resolve(yourApiData);*/
  }, function(err) {
    console.log(err); // Error: "It broke"
  });
```